# ¿Cómo regresar $row md5 en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, md5

Estoy tratando de enviar un dato de mysql por correo electrónico pero este se envía encriptado ya que se encuentra con un hash en md5.

Ya todo funciona solo necesito enviarlo correctamente descifrado. Ya intente encerrando el $row en paréntesis pero no funciona:

`md5($row['password']);`

Este es mi código completo:

```
<?php
//Reseteo variables.
$error = $usuario = NULL;

//Comprobamos si esta definida el formulario y no es NULL.
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

//Comprobamos que no este vacio nuestro input.
if (empty($_POST['emailRec'])) {
    $error = 'El email es obligatorio';
} else {
    //Importante, añadir la conexion donde se va utilizar.
    require_once'funcs/database.php';
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conectar, $_POST['emailRec']);
}

//Si es verdadero nuestro input, continuamos.
if ($usuario) {
    //Sentencia
    $sql = $conectar->query("SELECT * FROM empresasregistradas WHERE email = 
  '$usuario' LIMIT 1");
    //Comprobamos si existe el registro.
    if ($sql->num_rows===1) {
        $row = $sql->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

        //Componentes nuestro correo electronico
        require_once("PHPMailer-5.2.11/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

        //Nuevo correo electronico.
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        $mail->Username = "account@mail.com";
        $mail->Password = "psw";
        $mail->setFrom('account@mail.com', 'myweb');
        $mail->addAddress($usuario);
        //Titulo email.
        $mail->Subject = "Recuperar Contraseña / myweb";
        //Cuerpo email con HTML.
        $mail->Body = "Tu contraseña actualizada es: ".$row['password']; <---- 
    ----Dato encriptado

        //Comprobamos el envio.
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            $error = "Ocurrió un error inesperado con él envió del correo 
  electrónico, inténtelo de nuevo más tarde, disculpa las molestias.";
        } else {
            $error = "Se envio correctamente el correo electrónico.";
        }
    } else { //0 registros.
        $error = 'El email ingresado no existe en nuestros registros.';
    } $sql->close();
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: No es aconsejable en ningún caso enviar datos sensibles y mucho menos contraseñas a través de correo electrónico. Los protocolos de correo electrónico no son seguros y cualquiera que intercepte la comunicación entre los servidores de correo podrá ver el texto de los correos electrónicos.

Comment: No deberías encriptar con md5 en la propia documentación de php indican que no es seguro: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.md5.php mejor usar passsword_hash: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe una forma sencilla de desencriptar el MD5, la opción para que tus usuarios recuperen su cuenta es que antes de enviar el correo CAMBIAS su contraseña y envíes esa nueva, o generes un link para cambio de contraseña.

```php
// crear un nuevo password tomando los caracteres entre 4 y el 10.
// la nueva contraseña sera de max 8 y minimo 4 caracteres
$new_password = substr($row['password'], rand(4,5), rand(9,12))

// actualizar, recuerda encriptar
...
 "UPDATE SET password=MD5('$new_password')"
...
// ademas puede agregar un estado para que se le obligue cambiar
// contraseña al ingresar.
...
" UPDATE SET cambiar=true ..."
...

// enviar el nuevo password
$mail->Subject = "Recuperar Contraseña / myweb";
//Cuerpo email con HTML.
$mail->Body = "Tu contraseña actualizada es: ".$new_password." recuerda cambiarla frecuentemente";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me ha servido...

Comment: Una mala práctica ya que le envías la contraseña por un protocolo no seguro como es el mail. Es mejor crear un enlace para crear una contraseña nueva.

Answer (score 2):

Teóricamente imposible, las funciones hash son uni-direccionales.

Para lograr tu objetivo deberás almacenar el valor original ó enviar el correo antes de aplicar el md5. De lo contrario tendrías que utilizar otro algoritmo que sea bi-direccional y usar la función `openssl_decrypt` de php.

Comment: Entonces no existe algúna forma de hacer consultas almacenadas con datos md5?

Comment: Puedes hacer la consulta, pero al recuperar el dato prácticamente sólo puedes hacer comparaciones con él.